# Two login authentication ways in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need develop an app with two authentication endpoints: one a login web form and other sending credentials via custom token.

I create two **`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`** and the login forms work perfectly but the token not: When I tried to identify via token, it run ok but always redirect to de login form page.

This is my configuration:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), CustomAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(PublicUrls.URLS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .cors()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
}
```

.. and the token configuration:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .mvcMatcher(LOGINJWT)
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(LOGINJWT).permitAll()
               .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
               .and()
            .logout()
               .invalidateHttpSession(true)
               .clearAuthentication(true)
               .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
               .permitAll();
         // @formatter:on
}
```

When I trie to authenticate via token, it run the **`customFilter`**, and the custom authentication provider correctly but always redirect to login page.

The classes order annotation are this:

> 

```
     // Token annotation class
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {....}

//login annotation clas
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: the JWT filter is executing before `WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter`.

Comment: To make your answer more valueable, you should add the fixed code to your answer.